# Github Actions - How to Build and Deploy on push to master

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a github repo containing api documentation. On merging with master, I want to use github actions to do two things:

1. "Build" - update the index.html file using a python script
2. "Deploy" - sync the contents of the repo to S3

Here is the (simplified) repo structure:

```sh
.github/
  |-- workflows/
    |-- main.yml
    |-- build.py
dist/
  |-- index.html
```

**build.py** is the python script that will "build" the template by replacing some variables from the **dist/index.html**. The contents of the **dist** folder are then synced to AWS S3 using this github action:

```yaml
name: Upload Website

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master

jobs:

  # updates index.html:      
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Run a one-line script
      run: python ./.github/workflows/build.py
    ...
    - name: commit changed files
      run: git commit -m "Auto adding config files"
    - name: fetch from master
      run: git fetch origin master
    - name: push code to master
      run: git push origin HEAD:master

  # deploys latest version to s3:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Deploy static site to S3 bucket
      run: aws s3 sync ./dist <BUCKET DESTINATION>
```

The deploy part works fine on its own but I am having trouble with the build part. Will this cause an infinite loop? The action is set to run on push to master, but the action also pushes the updated template to master. If yes, how can I avoid this?

I am following [this](https://github.community/t/can-github-actions-directly-edit-files-in-a-repository/17884/7) example for the build part.

Comment: what is purpose of build part for you ?

Answer (score 0):

An infinite loop will happen if there is a push to master branch. And build part will be run.

In build part it will push again to master so an infinite loop happenning.

Remove this part from build stage:

```
- name: commit changed files
  run: git commit -m "Auto adding config files"
- name: fetch from master
  run: git fetch origin master
- name: push code to master
  run: git push origin HEAD:master
```

Comment: I see - so this will still update the file in the master branch? Will it be reflected on github?

Comment: I don't see the changes on the master branch - maybe a good approach is to use a second branch for deployment?

Comment: you can change `HEAD:master` to other one , and try again, whats purpose of that part

Answer (score 0):

You may find this comment helpful on how the GITHUB_TOKEN generated during workflows is created to avoid loops: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26970

Based off your code and that comment, if you're using the autogenerated token, then you shouldn't have an issue with loops. I've tested this successfully in our own workflow that has a similar pattern.